# Map Reduce- passing output of mapper as dictionary within a dictionary to reducer

Tags: python, file-io, hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce

​My mapper python script produces output as `[2323223,[{'word':'hi'},{'charcount':'2'}]`
In the output, `2323223` is the key and rest all are values of key `2323223` but again in values, there are multiple key value pairs in dictionary.

part of my mapper script​​:

```
 analysis = {}
 wordanalysis = {}
 found = True

 for line in sys.stdin:
 (n1,n6) = re.split("\t+",line.strip())
 #n6 are the words and n1 is id
 words= re.split("\s+", n6.strip().lower())


 for i in range(0, len(words)):
  #adding id to a dictionary
   #n1 is id
    analysis[n1] = wordanalysis
    wordanalysis["word"] = words[i]
    wordanalysis["charcount"]= len(words[i])

    if len(words[i]) > 7:
       wordanalysis["longword"] = found
    else:
       wordanalysis["longword"] = not(found)
```

Something like that. My reducer should act like count the number of words etc but how will it interpret the dictionary that has been there.. like In reducer:
for line in sys.stdin:

Output from mapper:

```
['34324242'] [{'word': 'hi','charcount': 2}]
['897924242'] [{'word': 'hello','charcount': 5}]
```

This is my output. I am passing this value from mapper script to reducer script. The reducer takes the above o/p as input and does data analysis such as total of charcount. Any idea how to do that? 

The main challenge is to get the dict values from mapper output and how would I retrieve them as per the keys from dict.

Thanks.​

Comment: You want us to write the reducer function? BTW, what is the input to this mapper function? There might be an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Yes I want to understand how will reducer take dictionary within a dictionary as input. Input is for example,  588864       hi there <br>

Comment: But you dont have a dictionary within a dictionary.

Comment: [2323223,[{'word':'hi'},{'charcount':'2'}] is dictionary within dictionary

Comment: Thats a dictionary within a list.

Comment: If you see I have declared analysis as {} which is dictionary.  But wondering how is it a list. How would I change the code so its dict within dict and then reducer can interpret as key value pair

Comment: do you try to implement map-reduce framework yourself?

Comment: @alko yes I did. I have done a lot of them otherwise except now I don't understand how will the reducer interpret dict within dict and use values as key value pairsd